# Evaluating 6D Gaussian Integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerics

I have to compute the accuracy of a new Gaussian mixture fitting algorithm. One of the tests include computing the probabilities in certain intervals in a 6D hyperspace. Also, the integral of the square of the difference between PDF has to be evaluated. But problem is, Matlab doesn't have library functions that handle integrals above 3 dimensions. Googling, I found several results that involve some sort of nesting using wither quad2d or integral2/integral3. Unfortunately, my attempts to implement nesting haven't been successful. All I have to do is to evaluate the Integral of $(N_{1}(x,\mu_{1},P_{1})-N_{2}(x,\mu_{2},P_{2}))^{2}$ over any given interval in $R^{6}$. Thank you for suggestions

Comment: Is evaluating $N_1,N_2$ expensive? Or can you do it a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 6):

In general, the standard quadrature codes do not perform well in higher dimensions, which is probably why they are not available in Matlab.

I would propose that you use [Monte Carlo Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) instead, which works very well in these cases. Here you randomly sample points of your function in order to evaluate the integral.
In particular, you probably want to use [Quasi Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Monte_Carlo_method) integration, as the convergence is faster. The only difference is that the function is not sampled randomly, but quasi-randomly. You can generate quasi-random numbers in [Matlab very easily](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/generating-quasi-random-numbers.html).

A simple way to estimate the precision is to simply repeat the integration twice, and look at the difference. However there are also [online algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) that allow you to estimate the variance as part of the Monte Carlo integration.

In practice, when the function is well behaved it is often sufficient to just use a large number of points and not worry unduly.

Answer (score 3):

One approach to higher dimensional integrals is to use a sparse grid quadrature method (smolyak, clenshaw-curtis, etc...).  The idea is to use a small portion of a tensor product of 1D quadrature rules such that certain multivariate monomials are accounted for in the final integration rule.  If the integrand is reasonably approximated by a low dimensional polynomial function, sparse grid quadrature work really well.  In which case, various matlab packages are available for this purpose:

[Matlab's Sparse Grid Quadrature Package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19063-sparse-grid-quadrature)

or

[www.sparse-grids.de](http://www.sparse-grids.de/)

For more (introductory) information about sparse grids, you may want to look at some of [John Burkardt's Presentations](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/presentations/sparse_2014_fsu.pdf) on high dimensional integration.